# pagination and multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, object, multidimensional-array, pagination, appendchild

This is my code. My result is correct but I have this error in the console : TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild is not an object.

item is 2 dimensional array.

```
    appendChildren(buttons, pages.map(function (page, index) {
            var button = document.createElement("button");
            button.addEventListener("click", display);
            button.innerHTML = index + 1;
            return button;
        }));

        appendChildren(items, page.items.map(function (item, index) {

            var index = index + 1
            idMarque = "marque" + (index);
            idImage = "image" + (index);
            numero = list.indexOf(item);

        }));

        function appendChildren(element, children) {
            children.forEach(function (child) {
                element.appendChild(child);
            });
        }
```

This is the result of my console.log
!https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-V_WnitWzswKruXcxr8oeVjOZicRcBTW

Comment: what are u trying to achieve? if possible add a snippet..

Comment: you are not returning anything from the map function in your 2nd appendChildren call

Comment: can u do console.log(children) in  func appendChildren and paste result here?

Comment: This is the result of my console.log !https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-V_WnitWzswKruXcxr8oeVjOZicRcBTW